# Windows Software for Designing Fonts

Tags: fonts, font-face, truetype, typeface

(Not sure if this belongs on SO, but no other Stack Exchange site seemed fitting...)

I have a few projects on the go that I'd like to design my own fonts for, but I want to make them into real TTF fonts, rather than just vector graphics. I've "Googled" the subject multiple times, but all I can find for results are people who are font designers.

Do you guys have any suggestions? Or perhaps other software like PhotoShop or Adobe Illustrator are capable of this through a plug-in? (I'm willing to buy the software; it doesn't have to be freeware.)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say it belongs on SuperUser, since it's really about using existing software, not creating new software. The short answer is that yes, there are such things available. For a few examples, see: http://www.high-logic.com/fontcreator.html, http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/, and http://www.fontlab.com/fontlab-products/.

Comment: Ah, I thought so... I'll keep it in mind for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many applications who offer you the possibility of creating real fonts. You're right, vector graphics editor applications don't really meet your needs.

**Free Software**

- [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) (Windows, Linux, OS X)
- <s>[Gbdfed](http://www.math.nmsu.edu/~mleisher/Software/gbdfed/)</s> (Linux, OS X)

**Proprietary Software**

- [Fontographer](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/) (Windows, Mac OS X)
- [FontLab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/) (Windows, Mac OS X)
- [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/fontcreator.html) (Windows)
- [CR8type](http://www.cr8software.net/type.html) (Windows)
- [Softy](http://users.breathe.com/l-emmett/) (Windows)
- [Private Character Editor](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/prelim_pceditor_overview.mspx?mfr=true) (Windows)

I'm sure you'll be fine with open-source software at first. I'd recommend you to try out FontForge. However, as soon as you feel that certain features are missing, don't hesitate and try out the proprietary software as well.